# groovy output in a map

Tags: dictionary, groovy, output

I have below groovy,

```
def terraformOutputLocal(Map params) {
terraformOutputAttributes = "terraform output".execute().text
}

def terraformOutputValues = terraformOutputLocal()
println terraformOutputValues
```

Above is going to give me output as,

```
billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
name = "testing-table"
stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
```

I would like to get this output as a map as below,

```
[billing_mode:PAY_PER_REQUEST, name:testing-pipeline-test-table, stream_view_type:NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on newlines, then split each line on `=` and collect them back into a map:

```
def terraformOutputLocal(Map params) {
    terraformOutputAttributes = "terraform output".execute().text
        .split('\n')*.split(' = ').collectEntries()
}
```

To remove double quotes from the strings, you can do:

```
def terraformOutputLocal(Map params) {
    terraformOutputAttributes = "terraform output".execute().text
        .split('\n')*.split(' = ')*.toList()
        .collectEntries { a, b -> [a, b[0] == '"' ? b[1..-2] : b] }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for this format you could use [ConfigSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html)

```
def terraformOutputValues  = '''
billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
name = "testing-table"
stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
'''

def c = new ConfigSlurper().parse(terraformOutputValues)
assert c.billing_mode == 'PAY_PER_REQUEST'
```